# Error (Xcode)flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons : Error: The 'super-parameters' language feature is disabled for this library

Tags: ios, flutter

```
Error (Xcode): lib/flutter/packages//animated_icons.dart:35:5: Error: The 'super-parameters' language
feature is disabled for this library.
```

Encountered error while building for device.

What should I do to enable the super-parameters feature

Comment: Can you share the package this error originates from? Also, your pubspec.yaml file will help as well.